# Python Dash does not display plot

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a dashboard where I take a string as an input, process it in backend, and then generate a graph to display as output. However, when I run, I only see the input field and on clicking Submit, nothing happens. The graph itself is 3 graphs side by side. Code attached below -

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Deal Forecast Dashboard'),
    dcc.Input(id='Deal_Name', value='Enter Deal Name', type='text'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button', type='submit', children='Submit'),
    dcc.Graph(id='forecast-graph')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='forecast-graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('Deal_Name', 'value')]
)

def update_graph(clicks, input_value):
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3)

    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(forecast_res, x="MONTH", y="CPY_VEC"),
        row=1, col=1
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(forecast_res, x="MONTH", y="CDR_VEC"),
        row=1, col=2
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(forecast_res, x="MONTH", y="DQ_VEC"),
        row=1, col=3
    )

    fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Forecast vectors")

    return fig

app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: Result as seen now]

Code attached and image attached

Comment: What happens if you add `figure={}` to your `dcc.Graph` in the layout? Sometimes Dash doesn't like props being left out.

Comment: Tried it as  'dcc.Graph(id='forecast-graph', figure={})', no change.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have the rest of the code and sample data to share so I could try running this locally?

Answer (score 0):

Your code to construct the dashboard is great!  No issues there - but you haven't defined what `forecast_res` is before references it in the `update_graph` function.

Can you edit your post and provide a link to the data and assign it to `forecast_res`?